# How should I flag issues that go outside a single question

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

There was a question on Worldbuilding that was closed:

[I need a way to transfer two men from a submarine to a sunken rocket](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109382/i-need-a-way-to-transfer-two-men-from-a-submarine-to-a-sunken-rocket)

A few days later, I saw this question:

[How can I transfer two men from a submarine to a sunken rocket?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109889/how-can-i-transfer-two-men-from-a-submarine-to-a-sunken-rocket)

The user repeated the question word-for-word with no attempt at correcting the problem. This time, instead of voting to close, I flagged the question with this comment:

> Reposing a closed question word for word

My flag was declined with this message:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Is someone abusing the system in this way not something that needs moderator attention? What is the correct way of handling problems where the user seems to be going past the limits of just closing a question?

Comment: Did you link to the original post?  That's a pretty important part of any flag for that reason.

Comment: @Servy there was already a mark as duplicate that connected the posts

Answer (score 1):

*In general*, for cases that don't concern singular posts, a custom flag *anywhere* with links for full context should do.

In this case, however, the flag being declined is *entirely justified*: there is a clear-cut correct thing to do that you could do yourself: *regardless* of whether the original question is opened or closed, a **verbatim** repost should be promptly closed as a duplicate, then deleted if possible.

If it doesn't get closed, *then* you should escalate to custom flags, followed by a Meta post if that in turn doesn't work.

Comment: I **think** that the point was not closing the question. The point was that an user reposted the same content multiple times in an attempt to game the system. The moderation intervention wasn't requested to delete the post, that is something anyone can do. The moderator was required to let the user know his behavior was a borderline abuse of the system. I know that anyone could do the same... but I think that a warning from (for example) Shog has much more weight than one from "generic SE user #23875562"